# Liferay API update Data with JSON

Tags: json, api, liferay

I am working on an API for my Portal, to provide users the ability to update there data via API directly from there internal Systems.
Liferay 6.2 bundle Tomcat. (for api call testing I use soapUI)

The get Methods work fine, (I have getAll, and getByID). getByID returns a JSON Object like this:

```
{
     "ID": "ORGANIZATIONID",
     "type": "ORGANIZATIONTYPE", 
     "name": "ORGANIZATIONNAME",
     "URI": "ORGANIZATIONNAMEURI"
     "date of inclusion": "INCLUTIONDATE", 
     "last activities": "LASTMODIFIEDDATE",
     "address": {
         "name of host institution": "NAMEOFHOSTINSTITUTE",
         "street1": "STREET1",
         "street2" : "STREET2",
         "zip": "ZIP",
         "city": "CITY",
         "country": "COUNTRY",
     },
     "url": [{"ORGANIZATIONURL"}],
     "main contact": {
         "first name": "FIRSTNAME",
         "last name" : "LASTNAME",
         "phone": "PHONE",
         "email": "MAINCONTACTEMAIL"
     },
     "type of host institution" : "TYPEOFHOSTINSTITUTE", 
     "diseases":  [
        {
         "name": "DISEASENAME1",
         "number": "SAMPLECOUNT",
         "gene": "GENE", 
         "orphacode": "ORPHA"
         "icd10": "ICD",
         "omim": "OMIM";
         "synonym": "SYNONYM" 
        },
        {
         "name": "DISEASENAME2",
         "number": "SAMPLECOUNT",
         "gene": "GENE", 
         "orphacode": "ORPHA"
         "icd10": "ICD",
         "omim": "OMIM";
         "synonym": "SYNONYM" 
        }
     ]
}
```

I would like to have an API for Updating the diseases information for an organization. I have created a URL service where everything is in the url as parameters, but I would like to have it that the in the url only the id parameter is send and the rest of the information in a JSON object. Like:
/api/jsonws/....-portlet...../updateregbb/organization-id/16016/
and the data:

```
{
     "ID": "ORGANIZATIONID",
     "diseases":  [
        {
         "name": "DISEASENAME1",
         "number": "SAMPLECOUNT",
         "gene": "GENE", 
         "orphacode": "ORPHA"
         "icd10": "ICD",
         "omim": "OMIM";
         "synonym": "SYNONYM" 
        },
        {
         "name": "DISEASENAME2",
         "number": "SAMPLECOUNT",
         "gene": "GENE", 
         "orphacode": "ORPHA"
         "icd10": "ICD",
         "omim": "OMIM";
         "synonym": "SYNONYM" 
        }
     ]
}
```

But I could not find a solution how I can read the JSON data:

```
@JSONWebService(value = "updateregbb", method = "POST")
public void updateregbb2(long organizationId, Map jsondata) {



@JSONWebService(value = "updateregbb", method = "POST")
public void updateregbb(long organizationId, JSONObject json) {
```

How can I get the Data into my function?

Thanks for the help, 
Best
Robert

Comment: Why don't you give us a clue that this is also well discussed in the Liferay Forums already? https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/56332482

Comment: Can you try creating Disease POJO class  and provide List<Disease> as second argument of update functions.?